# 'x people chatting' tooltip in sidebar doesn't make sense!

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips, grammar, sidebar

Hovering over the 'x people chatting' link in the sidebar shows:

[image: "11 users active in 3 rooms the last 60 minutes"]

> 11 users active in 3 rooms the last 60 minutes

---

It should probably be:

> 11 users active in 3 rooms ***in*** the last 60 minutes